# Route::resource and Route::controller equivalent for Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm building a little Lumen application, but I'm unable to figure out the equivalent of Laravel's `Route::resource` and `Route::controller` function for Lumen.

Answer (score 4):

Lumen is a microframework, engineered for performance rather than extensive functionality. It doesn't use the full Laravel router, so there are no `Route::resource` or `Route::controller` functions.

You can manually define similar routes, if you like.

Comment: I keep seeing the "it's a microframework" line used quite dismissively to nearly everyone who asks this question. Resource routing and a fast, small router should not have to be mutually exclusive—given how much Lumen is geared toward developing APIs, REST resource routing still makes a great deal of sense as a feature. I'd like to see a real proposal to add it to a future version of Lumen.

Comment: @ches I believe it's possible to pull in the main Laravel routing engine if you want. I tend to avoid the automatic routing functions even in Laravel itself in favor of explicitly declaring mine.

Comment: The FastRoute-based router is, I presume, a significant factor in Lumen's performance though. I wouldn't expect `Route::controller` to ever be fast without using caching, but I'd love to see resource routes implemented on top of FastRoute.

Comment: Has anyone attempted to replace `FastRoute` with the regular `Illuminate\Routing\Router` router in a Lumen project?

Comment: @ches is right this, is a very basic feature for APIs development site which is what I'm using it for. I'm really considering Yii again only because of this....is really annoying.

Comment: @GabrielRodriguez If you're willing to use Yii - a full-featured framework - you could always just use Laravel. Lumen is a Laravel-based **micro**framework.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, you are right I could use the full Laravel....is just like I came from Yii and my main reason to switch to Lumen was because of speed, .... and....anyway....you get my point.

Comment: @GabrielRodriguez The downside of Lumen's speed is it has fewer features. This means you have to write a few more route declarations than `Route::resource` would've required. I don't think that's an insane tradeoff.

Comment: @ceejayoz not only `Route::resource` but `Route::controller` also ;)...But anyway, I just installed and made some performance tuning to Laravel, and Im getting very decent speeds simillar to Lucem

Comment: @GabrielRodriguez You might also consider using [Dingo](https://github.com/dingo/api) with Lumen, it adds back a resource route helper and some other useful feature extensions for API apps.